# How can I get IntelliJ to automatically insert tabs/indents?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

In a code block like this ( '|' representing the caret position):

```
public void myMethod(){
|
}
```

The caret position is at the start. I want the line to automatically insert the tabs/indents to the line so it looks like this:

```
public void myMethod(){
    |
}
```

I know it's just me being lazy but Eclipse had this feature and I'd like to know how to get IntelliJ to do this too.
Thanks.

Comment: I get this behavior when I for example write the method private void foo() { and then press enter. IntelliJ generates the missing } and places the caret at the correct position. In which cases doesn't intellij place the cursor there?

Comment: Yeah it does but if I click off and goto another tab then go back and click onto the line, the caret moves to the back of the line.

Comment: I don't have this behavior either... hmm try this setting: Editor, Section virtual spaces "Allow placement of caret after end of line" <- check...

Comment: That lets me place the caret wherever the mouse position is, but I want it to just be at where the tabs/indents should be.

Comment: I just thought may be this is the difference since I don't have your described behavior in Intellij 13.1.4.

Comment: I'm also using IntelliJ 13.1.4.
So when you click onto an unmodified tab and click on an empty line inside a method or class, the caret position isn't at the start?

Comment: Ah yes, if I click again then the caret position is wrong. (I never click, I rarely use the mouse so I naturally didn't click the first couple of times I tried you scenario.) If you just switch tabs with Ctrl + Tab then the caret stays where it should be.

Comment: Okay, I guess there's nothing I can do then apart from just not use the mouse lol. Thanks.

Comment: If I move into an empty line in a method the cursor will jump to the left border (because the line is empty), but if I press the end key the cursor jumps to the correct tab ready to code.

Comment: That's the best solution right now so thanks for that!

Comment: Check the smart keys settings under: IDE settings -> Smart Keys, especially the "Smart indent" option. Also try out the "complete current statement" feature (Ctrl + Shift + Enter).

Answer (score 0):

You can ctrl + alt + l and refactor & reformat your code. You can do this before or after selecting the specific code block to be refactored.